# Apache phoenix not getting started

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have installed HBase 1.1.3 on multi cluster configuration and wanted to run Apache phoenix over it. I download phoenix 4.7, installed it as per the guidelines mentioned here: https://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html

> But when i am running the following command: sqlline.py 
>   it is getting hanged till the point shown below.

```
hadoop@hostname:~$ sqlline.py hostname
Setting property: [incremental, false]
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-bin/phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
16/05/10 13:06:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: Start with debug mode to see where it is hanged.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the Phoenix client is unable to connect to the Hbase z-node present at zookeeper cluster. Please do the following :

1. Check if zookeeper is up .
2. Check with what name you have registered hbase at the zookeeper.If the name is not hbase we need to specify it to the client. in that case the command would look like sqlline.py hostname:2181:/znode-for-hbase-name.
3. Please check if u have added phoenix-[version]-server.jar to the lib folder in all hbase nodes and try again .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following jars to Hbase/lib directory.

- **phoenix-spark-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.jar**
- **phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-server.jar**